# How to move a row with buttons?

Tags: java, android

I need you help.

I made a small application, and it is necessary to bring "tiles" button.

Now i have an array with letters

```
 <string-array name="let_terms">
        <item>A</item>
        <item>B</item>
        <item>C</item>
......
```

And then programmatically output the button with these letters:

```
public class letterms extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] mArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.letterms);

        int length =0;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        length =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.let_terms).length;

        mArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.let_terms);

        final LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);

        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){

            final String nazv = mArray[i];
            final String[] splittedItem = nazv.split(":");

                Button button=new Button(this);
                button.setId(i);
                button.setWidth(20);
            button.setLayoutParams(params);
                button.setText(splittedItem[0]);
                button.setTextColor(0xFF2C85A6);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent is = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), termin_full.class);
                        is.putExtra("fVariableName", nazv);
                        startActivity(is);
                    }
                });

                linearLayout.addView(button);
        }

    }
}
```

In XML:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/buttonlayout">

        </LinearLayout>
```

All right, go bat buttons in a row, and I would like to carry on a new line when it reaches the end of the screen. How to tile...

Where can I see an example of such an implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use vertical LinearLayout in XML. Then programmatically create horizontal LinearLayout and add buttons in horizontal layout. For each line, create and add new horizontal layout.

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonlayout">
</LinearLayout>
```

ACTIVITY:

```
public class letterms extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] mArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.letterms);

        int length =0;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        length =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.let_terms).length;

        mArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.let_terms);

        final LinearLayout verticalLayout= LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);

        int verticalWidth = verticalLayout.getWidth();
        int numberOfButtonsPerLine = (verticalWidth/buttonWidth);
        int numberOfLines = (length/numberOfButtonsPerLine) + 1;

        for(int i=0;i<length;){
          LinearLayout newLine = new LinearLayout(this);
          newLine.setLayoutParams(params);
          newLine.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
          for(int j=0;j<numberOfLines;j++){

            final String nazv = mArray[i];
            final String[] splittedItem = nazv.split(":");

                Button button=new Button(this);
                button.setId(i);
                button.setWidth(20);
                button.setLayoutParams(params);
                button.setText(splittedItem[0]);
                button.setTextColor(0xFF2C85A6);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent is = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), termin_full.class);
                        is.putExtra("fVariableName", nazv);
                        startActivity(is);
                    }
                });

                newLine.addView(button);
                i++;
                if(i>=length) {
                   break;
                }
          }
          verticalLayout.addView(newLine);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, the script compiles successfully, but the application crashes

Comment: When i do
      //  int numberOfLines = (length/numberOfButtonsPerLine) + 1;
        int numberOfLines = 5; //for example

The script begins to be executed, but then freezes and crashes too.
How to understand what is the reason?

Comment: I understood. Typo here
for(int j=0;**i**<numberOfLines;j++){
i do 
for(int j=0;j<numberOfLines;j++){

and I got the result

A A A A A

Comment: Sorry. And I got the result

A A A A A

Comment: Sorry. And I got the result

A A A A A
B B B B B
C C C C C
D D D D D

And it is necessary that it

A B C D E
F G H I J
K L M N 0
....

Comment: Sorry. And I got the result 
`A A A A A 
B B B B B 
C C C C C 
D D D D D `
And it is necessary that it 
`A B C D E 
F G H I J 
K L M N 0 
...`

Comment: I edited my answer. Add "i++; if(i<length) {break;} " at the end of inner for loop.

Comment: Now everything is in one column

Comment: Instead  

int verticalWidth = verticalLayout.getWidth();

I did

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int verticalWidth = display.getWidth(); 

and the problem has disappeared with crashes
It remains to understand why the buttons are repeated in rows

Comment: Sorry. Try "i++; if(i>=length) {break;} "

Comment: TNX. Thanks It works! I removed i++ from (int i=0;i<length;i++)and it work now!

Answer (score 0):

GridLayout is the best option for your scenario. By GridLayout you don't need to calculate the width of the screen.

You can find the guide for it on the link below.

[GridView guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)